# Where is the local node.js from the electron framework located?

Tags: linux, node.js

**Additional information:**

I use the framework [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) in combination with node native modules [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) and bleno to access bluetooth adapter functionality (noble and bleno are build against electrons node version with [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild)). Electron is using its own node version instead of the systems node version.

**Problem description:**

Noble however requires me to run electron as root to access the bluetooth device.

Since this isn't a good solution for production use, I tried the official command `sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip $(eval readlink -fwhich node)` but this sets the permissions only for the systems node version.

I figured that I should then use the same command and replace the subshell command `$(eval readlink -fwhich node)` with the local node version electron uses.

So far I have failed to find the correct location of electrons node.js.

**Question:**
So where is electrons local node.js located ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Apparently it's located in `./node_modules/electron/dist`
in this directory you will find the electron binary and `libnode.so`

**Additional information:**

If you try to use `setcap` to add permissions for electron on .`/node_modules/electron/dist/electron` it will complain about missing the shared lib `libnode.so` even though its there.
This is a intended by linux and you have to link it manually, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843178/linux-capabilities-setcap-seems-to-disable-ld-library-path) about it.